# Is there a Java parser for BER-TLV?

Tags: java, parsing, tlv

I'm new to Java, so I would like to use the standard solution for, I think, the standard task. The length of tags and values ​​are not known.

Comment: might be this the one that you need? 
https://github.com/VakhoQ/tlv-encoder

Answer (score 6):

You can use this BER-TLV parser: [source code on git](https://github.com/evsinev/ber-tlv). 
Examples: 
**How to parse**

```
byte[] bytes = HexUtil.parseHex("50045649534157131000023100000033D44122011003400000481F");
BerTlvParser parser = new BerTlvParser(LOG);
BerTlvs tlvs = parser.parse(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

**How to build**

```
byte[] bytes =  new BerTlvBuilder()
                .addHex(new BerTag(0x50), "56495341")
                .addHex(new BerTag(0x57), "1000023100000033D44122011003400000481F")
                .buildArray();
```

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.payneteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>ber-tlv</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial in [here](http://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/) gives a tips on how to parse BER-TLV. Using [JACCAL](http://jaccal.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader) project contains [some code to parse BER-TLV](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader/blob/f0d5920a94a0dc4be505fbb5dd03a7f1992f82bc/src/main/java/sasc/iso7816/TLVUtil.java).

Answer (score 1):

Example C# code for bertTlv decode

[Code Details here](https://github.com/umitkoc/BertTlv/blob/main/Tlv.cs)

```
public class Tlv : ITlv, IFile
{
    List<TlvModel> modelList=new();
    string parser = "";
    string length = "";
    String empty = "";
    string ascii = "";
    int decValue = 0;
    int step = 0;
    public Tlv(String data)
    {
        TlvParser(data.Replace(" ",""));
    }
    public void readTag()
    {
        String line = "";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("taglist.txt");
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            modelList.Add(new()
            {
                tag = line.Split(",")[0].Trim(),
                description = line.Split(",")[1].Trim()
            });

        }
        sr.Close();


    }
    public void insertTag()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
            foreach (var item in modelList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"{item.tag},{item.description}");
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }

    }
    public int writeFile(String parser)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(parser);
        sw.Close();
        return 0;
    }

    private int TlvParser(String data, int i = 0, string tag = "")
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            readTag();
        }
        if (i < data.Length)
        {
            tag += data[i];
            TlvModel model = getTag(tag);
            if (model != null)
            {

                decValue = int.Parse(data.Substring(i + 1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                // lengthControl(data,i+3,decValue);
                if (model.description.Contains("Template"))
                {
                    parser += $"{empty}|------ tag: {model.tag}({model.description})\n";
                    step += 1;
                    empty = Empty();
                    return TlvParser(data, i + 3, "");
                }
                else
                {
                    parser += $"{empty}|------ tag: {model.tag}({model.description}){empty}|------ value -->  {ConvertHex(data.Substring(i + 3, decValue * 2))} \n";
                }
                i += 3 + decValue * 2;
                return TlvParser(data, i, "");

            }
            else
            {
                return TlvParser(data, i + 1, tag);
            }
        }
        return writeFile(parser);

    }

    public TlvModel getTag(string tag)
    {
        return modelList.Find(i => i.tag == tag);
    }

    public string ConvertHex(string hex)
    {

        ascii = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
        {
            ascii += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16));
        }
        return ascii;
    }

    private string Empty()
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < step; s++)
        {
            empty += "\t";
        }
        return empty;
    }

    public void setTag(TlvModel model)
    {
        modelList.Add(model);
        insertTag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [Javacard](http://javacard.kenai.com/javadocs/connected/javacardx/framework/tlv/ConstructedBERTLV.html) classes for BER TLV.  Hope those help

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple parser based on the information provided here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/669147/Simple-TLV-Parser

I don't know if this code support all the standard, but it works for me.

```
public static Map<String, String> parseTLV(String tlv) {
    if (tlv == null || tlv.length()%2!=0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid tlv, null or odd length");
    }
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i=0; i<tlv.length();) {
        try {
            String key = tlv.substring(i, i=i+2);

            if ((Integer.parseInt(key,16) & 0x1F) == 0x1F) {
                // extra byte for TAG field
                key += tlv.substring(i, i=i+2);
            }
            String len = tlv.substring(i, i=i+2);
            int length = Integer.parseInt(len,16);

            if (length > 127) {
                // more than 1 byte for lenth
                int bytesLength = length-128;
                len = tlv.substring(i, i=i+(bytesLength*2));
                length = Integer.parseInt(len,16);
            }
            length*=2;

            String value = tlv.substring(i, i=i+length);
            //System.out.println(key+" = "+value);
            hashMap.put(key, value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing number",e);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error processing field",e);
        }
    }

    return hashMap;
}
```

Comment: simple-tlv is different from ber-tlv, and a simple tlv parser will often crash on ber-tvl data

Answer (score 0):

Might be [this free library](https://github.com/VakhoQ/tlv-encoder) can be useful for you. I've used this one for simple TLV parsing. Anyway it's with MIT license and you can modify it.

```
https://github.com/VakhoQ/tlv-encoder
```