# How to decode APDU GPO response wrapped in tag 77

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, emv, tlv

I followed [this](https://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/) tutorial and I have recieved the following response from the GPO command:

```
7716820239009410100101011002020018010200200102009000
```

When I try parsing the response:

```
response tag = 77
AIP = ??
AFL = ??
```

Could some one help me with a method of getting the Application Interchange Profile (AIP) and Application File Locator (AFL). The tutorial explains only that with tag 80, and the reference book `EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification` says that tag `77` is out of their solution scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you got in return to the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command is in BER-TLV format and decodes like this:

```
77 16    [tag = Response Message Template Format 2, length = 22 bytes]
    82 02    [tag = Application Interchange Profile, length = 2 bytes]
        3900    [value = AIP]
    94 10    [tag = Application File Locator (AFL), length = 16 bytes]
        10010101100202001801020020010200    [value = AFL]

9000    [status word = no error]
```

For decoding BER-TLV by hand, you could use am online parser like https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/. For integration into your own application, you might want to have a look at [Is there a Java parser for BER-TLV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473974/2425802).

Comment: thanks alot for that structure @Micheal_Ronald, it looks implementable